# python how to delete a line from a txt file and add data

Tags: python

my program reads all txt files from a folder and convert the numbers in the txt files.
one of my txt file for example is this

```
1 0.487500 0.751667 0.112500 0.246667
0 0.464375 0.648333 0.046250 0.083333
4 0.500000 0.352500 0.055000 0.098333
```

they all have the same frame like above but the rows could have less or more.
so far i've been able to convert them using below code

```
import os


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for idx, file in enumerate(files):
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if ext in ['.txt']:
            with open((file),'r') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    item = line.split(" ")
                    item[1] = float(item[1])
                    item[1] = ((item[1]) * 800 - 256) / 288
                    item[1] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[1],6))
                    item[1] = str(item[1])

            
                    item[2] = float(item[2])
                    item[2] = ((item[2]) * 600 - 88) / 512
                    item[2] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[2],6))
                    item[2] = str(item[2])

            
                    item[3] = float(item[3])
                    item[3] = ((item[3]) * 800) / 288
                    item[3] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[3],6))
                    item[3] = str(item[3])



                    item[4] = float(item[4])
                    item[4] = ((item[4]) * 600) / 512
                    item[4] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[4],6))
                    item[4] = str(item[4])

                    item = ' '.join(item)
                    print (item)
```

and result using the above code and the txt file is

```
1 0.465278 0.708985 0.312500 0.289063
0 0.401042 0.587890 0.128472 0.097656
4 0.500000 0.241211 0.152778 0.115234
```

which works great but i need to replace the results to the original. how would i be able to do it?

Comment: `replace the results to the original` - you mean write the result back to the original file?

Comment: yes sir. sorry for my bad english. remove the original data and replace it with the result

Comment: Of course it depending on context, but I not sure if that it is a good idea to rewrite original files. It may cause data loss. I recommend to create new folder `processed` and move processed files into it. And after that write new file instead of moved one. That will allow you to re-process original data in case of troubles

Comment: I agree with _@rz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important**: It is preferred to write your results into new files, so that the original files don't get destroyed in case of a failure.

Either way, here is code that does what you specified:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def main():
    for _, _, files in os.walk('./'):
        for _, file in enumerate(files):
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            if ext in ['.txt']:
                processed_lines = list()

                with open(file, 'r') as f:
                    for line in f.readlines():
                        item = line.split(" ")
                        item[1] = float(item[1])
                        item[1] = ((item[1]) * 800 - 256) / 288
                        item[1] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[1], 6))
                        item[1] = str(item[1])

                        item[2] = float(item[2])
                        item[2] = ((item[2]) * 600 - 88) / 512
                        item[2] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[2], 6))
                        item[2] = str(item[2])

                        item[3] = float(item[3])
                        item[3] = ((item[3]) * 800) / 288
                        item[3] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[3], 6))
                        item[3] = str(item[3])

                        item[4] = float(item[4])
                        item[4] = ((item[4]) * 600) / 512
                        item[4] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[4], 6))
                        item[4] = str(item[4])

                        processed_lines.append(' '.join(item))

                with open(file, 'w') as f:
                    f.write('\n'.join(processed_lines))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Primarily, I added the `f.write()` call to write your data back to disk.

Apart of that, a couple of improvements I made:

- wrap the code in `main()`, as it is [best practice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)
- Replace all unused variables with `_`
- Minor beautifications

---

While the previous code is simple to understand for beginners, it has the drawback that it opens the file twice.

It is possible to keep the file open and use the same file object for both reading and writing, to improve performance:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def main():
    for _, _, files in os.walk('./'):
        for _, file in enumerate(files):
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            if ext in ['.txt']:
                processed_lines = list()

                # Open with 'r+', indicating that we want to both read
                # and write the file
                with open(file, 'r+') as f:
                    for line in f.readlines():
                        item = line.split(" ")
                        item[1] = float(item[1])
                        item[1] = ((item[1]) * 800 - 256) / 288
                        item[1] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[1], 6))
                        item[1] = str(item[1])

                        item[2] = float(item[2])
                        item[2] = ((item[2]) * 600 - 88) / 512
                        item[2] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[2], 6))
                        item[2] = str(item[2])

                        item[3] = float(item[3])
                        item[3] = ((item[3]) * 800) / 288
                        item[3] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[3], 6))
                        item[3] = str(item[3])

                        item[4] = float(item[4])
                        item[4] = ((item[4]) * 600) / 512
                        item[4] = '{:.6f}'.format(round(item[4], 6))
                        item[4] = str(item[4])

                        processed_lines.append(' '.join(item))

                    # Move the current position back to the beginning of the file
                    f.seek(0)

                    # Delete everything in the file
                    f.truncate()

                    # Write new content
                    f.write('\n'.join(processed_lines))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Further, here's a suggestion of how your function could be written in a more compact way:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def main():
    for _, _, files in os.walk('./'):
        for _, file in enumerate(files):
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            if ext in ['.txt']:
                processed_lines = list()

                # Open with 'r+', indicating we want both read and write the file
                with open(file, 'r+') as f:
                    for line in f.readlines():

                        item = line.split(" ")

                        numbers = list(map(float, item[1:5]))

                        numbers[0] = (numbers[0] * 800 - 256) / 288
                        numbers[1] = (numbers[1] * 600 - 88) / 512
                        numbers[2] = (numbers[2] * 800) / 288
                        numbers[3] = (numbers[3] * 600) / 512

                        item[1:5] = map(lambda el: '{:.6f}'.format(round(el, 6)), numbers)

                        processed_lines.append(' '.join(item))

                    # Move the current position back to the beginning of the file
                    f.seek(0)

                    # Delete everything in the file
                    f.truncate()

                    # Write new content
                    f.write('\n'.join(processed_lines))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```